# How to abstract non-linear list iteration schemes into a re-usable algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, f#, dsl

On the odd chance, that someone has a brilliant idea...

I am not sure if there is a good way to generalize that.

**EDIT**: I think it might be nice to explain exactly what the inputs and outputs are. The code below is only how I approached the solution.

Inputs: data, recipe

data: set of string, string list here also called "set of named lists"
recipe: list of commands

Command Print (literal|list reference)
Adds the literal to the output or if it is a list reference, it adds the head of the referenced list to the output.

Command While (list reference)
when referenced list not empty --> next command
when referenced list empty --> skip entries in recipe list past the matching Wend.

Command Wend (list reference)
replace referenced list with tail (reference list)
when referenced list is empty, next command
when referenced list is not empty, next command is the matching while above.

Outputs: string list

*The best answer is the implementation of that which is shortest and which allows to re-use that algorithm in new contexts.*

This is not just a programming problem for the fun of it, btw. It is basically what happens if you try to implement data driven text templating.

The code below is my attempt to solve this problem.
The first code snippet is a non-generalized solution.
The second code snippet is an attempt to isolate the algorithm.
If you play with the code, simply paste the second snippet below the first snippet and both versions are working.

The whole topic is about understanding better how to separate the iteration algorithm from the rest of the code and then to simply apply it, in contrast of having all the other code within.

Would it not be great, if there was a way to abstract the way the statements are being processed and the looping of the while/wend, such,
that it can be reused in my main code, just as I keep re-using other  "iteration schemes", such as List.map?

The commonalities between my main code and this study are:

1. An evolving "environment" which is threaded through all steps of the computation.
2. Collections, which need to be iterated in a well-formed nested manner. (Malformed would be: while x while y wend x wend y)
3. A series of "execution steps" form the body of each of those "while wend" loops.
4. Done in a "pure" manner. As you will note, nothing is mutable in the study. Want to keep it like that.
5. Each "While" introduces a new scope (as for binding values), which is discarded again, once the while loop is done.

So, I am looking for something like:

run: CommandClassifier -> commandExecutor -> Command list -> EnvType -> EnvType

where

CommandClassifier could be a function of the form  Command -> NORMAL|LOOP_START|LOOP_END

and commandexecutor: Command -> EnvType -> EnvType

Of course, nesting of those while-blocks would not be limited to 2 (just tried to keep the testProgram() small).

SideNote: the "commands list" is an AST from a preceding parser run, but that should not really matter.

```
type MiniLanguage =
    | Print of string
    | While of string
    | Wend of string

let testProgram = 
    [   Print("Hello, I am your Mini Language program")
        While("names")
        Print("<names>")
        While("pets")
        Print("<pets>")
        Wend("pets")
        Print("Done with pets.")
        Wend("names")
        Print("Done with names.")
    ]

type MiniEnvironment = { Bindings : Map<string,string>; Collections : Map<string, string list> }

let init collections =
    { Bindings = Map.empty; Collections = Map.ofList collections}

let bind n v env =
    let newBindings =
        env.Bindings
        |> Map.remove n
        |> Map.add n v
    { env with Bindings = newBindings; }

let unbind n env =
    { env with Bindings = Map.remove n env.Bindings; }

let bindingValue n env =
    if env.Bindings.ContainsKey n then
        Some(env.Bindings.Item n)
    else 
        None

let consumeFirstFromCollection n env =
    if env.Collections.ContainsKey n then
        let coll = env.Collections.Item n
        match coll with
        | [] -> env |> unbind n
        | _ ->
            let first = coll.Head
            let newCollections = 
                env.Collections
                |> Map.remove n
                |> Map.add n coll.Tail
            { env with Collections = newCollections } 
            |> bind n first
    else failwith ("Unknown collection: " + n)

// All do functions take env - the execution environment - as last argument.
// All do functions return (a new) env as single return parameter.
let rec doPrint (s : string) env = 
    if s.StartsWith("<") && s.EndsWith(">") then
        match bindingValue (s.Substring (1, s.Length - 2 )) env with
        | Some(v) -> v
        | _ -> s
    else s 
    |> printfn "%s"
    env

let rec skipPastWend name code =
    match code with
    | (Wend(cl) :: rest) when cl = name -> rest
    | [] -> failwith "No Wend found!"
    | (_ :: rest) -> skipPastWend name rest

let rec doWhileX name code env =
    match code with
    | (Print(s) :: rest) -> env |> (doPrint s) |> doWhileX name rest
    | (While(cn) :: rest) -> env |> doWhile cn rest |> ignore; env |> doWhileX name (skipPastWend cn rest)
    | (Wend(cn) :: rest) when cn = name -> env
    | [] -> failwith ("While without Wend for: " + name)
    | _ -> failwith ("nested while refering to same collection!")

and doWhile name code env =
    let e0 = env |> consumeFirstFromCollection name
    match bindingValue name e0 with
    | Some(s) ->
        e0 |> doWhileX name code |> doWhile name code
    | None -> env

let rec run (program : MiniLanguage list) env =
    match program with
    | (Print(s) :: rest) -> env |> (doPrint s) |> run rest
    | (While(cn) :: rest) -> 
        env 
        |> doWhile cn rest |> ignore
        env |> run (skipPastWend cn program)
    | (Wend(cn) :: rest) -> failwith "wend found in run()"
    | [] -> env

let test() =
    init [ "names", ["name1"; "name2"; "name3"; ]; "pets", ["pet1"; "pet2"] ] 
    |> run testProgram
    |> printfn "%A"

(*
Running test() yields:

Hello, I am your Mini Language program
name1
pet1
pet2
Done with pets.
name2
pet1
pet2
Done with pets.
name3
pet1
pet2
Done with pets.
Done with names.
{Bindings = map [];
 Collections =
  map [("names", ["name1"; "name2"; "name3"]); ("pets", ["pet1"; "pet2"])];}


*)
```

Here my first version of isolating the algorithm. The number of callbacks is not entirely pretty. Can anyone come up with something simpler?

```
// The only function I had to "modify" to work with new "generalized" algorithm.
let consumeFirstFromCollection1 n env =
    if env.Collections.ContainsKey n then
        let coll = env.Collections.Item n
        match coll with
        | [] -> (env |> unbind n , false)
        | _ ->
            let first = coll.Head
            let newCollections = 
                env.Collections
                |> Map.remove n
                |> Map.add n coll.Tail
            ({ env with Collections = newCollections } 
                |> bind n first , true)
    else failwith ("Unknown collection: " + n)

type NamedList<'n,'t when 'n : comparison> = 'n * List<'t>
type Action<'a,'c> = 'c -> 'a -> 'a
type LoopPreparer<'a,'c> = 'c -> 'a -> 'a * bool
type CommandType = | RUN | BEGIN | END
type CommandClassifier<'c> = 'c -> CommandType
type Skipper<'c> = 'c -> List<'c> -> List<'c>

type InterpreterContext<'a,'c> =
    { classifier : CommandClassifier<'c>
      executor : Action<'a,'c>
      skipper : Skipper<'c>
      prepareLoop : LoopPreparer<'a,'c>
      isMatchingEnd : 'c -> 'c -> bool
    }

let interpret (context : InterpreterContext<'a,'c>) (program : 'c list) (env : 'a) : 'a =
    let rec loop front (code : 'c list) e =
        let e0,hasData = e |> context.prepareLoop front
        if hasData 
        then 
            e0 
            |> loop1 front (code) 
            |> loop front (code) 
        else e

    and loop1 front code e =
        match code with
        | x :: more when (context.classifier x) = RUN -> 
            //printfn "RUN %A" x
            e |> context.executor x |> loop1 front more
        | x :: more when (context.classifier x) = BEGIN -> 
            //printfn "BEGIN %A" x
            e |> loop x more |> ignore
            e |> loop1 front (context.skipper x more)
        | x :: more when (((context.classifier x) = END) && (context.isMatchingEnd front x)) ->   ///  && (context.isMatchingEnd front x)
            //printfn "END %A" x
            e
        | [] -> failwith "No END."
        | _ -> failwith "TODO: Not sure which case this is. But it is not a legal one!"

    let rec interpr code e =
        match code with
        | [] -> e
        | (first :: rest) -> 
            match context.classifier first with
            | RUN -> env |> context.executor first |> interpr rest
            | BEGIN -> 
                e |> loop first rest |> ignore
                e |> interpr (context.skipper first rest)
            | END -> failwith "END without BEGIN."
    interpr program env



let test1() =
    let context : InterpreterContext<MiniEnvironment,MiniLanguage> = 
        {   classifier = fun c-> match c with | MiniLanguage.Print(_) -> RUN | MiniLanguage.While(_) -> BEGIN | MiniLanguage.Wend(_) -> END;
            executor = fun c env -> match c with | Print(s) -> doPrint s env | _ -> failwith "Not a known command.";
            skipper = fun c cl -> match c with | While(n) -> skipPastWend n cl | _ -> failwith "first arg of skipper SHALL be While!"
            prepareLoop = fun c env -> match c with | While(n) -> (consumeFirstFromCollection1 n env) | _ -> failwith "first arg of skipper SHALL be While!"
            isMatchingEnd = fun cwhile cx -> match cwhile,cx with | (While(n),Wend(p)) when n = p -> true | _ -> false
        }
    init [ "names", ["name1"; "name2"; "name3"; ]; "pets", ["pet1"; "pet2"] ]
    |> interpret context testProgram
    |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Belongs on code review? /*-/*-/

Comment: Is it not more about a refactoring technique? I did not ask for code review but for ideas on how else to tackle such a task/ alternative solutions on how to encapsulate an algorithm.

Comment: When you post 200 lines of code as dense as that, you're asking for code review whether you like it or not. It seems you have an interesting question there, but having to burn through such a sizable chunk of code is a showstopper for me at least.

Comment: This is the SMALL version - I spent quite an effort to reduce the problem to its minimum. There are only 3 commands in that "mini language". If you have an idea for an even smaller but to the point showcase, please let me know.

Comment: @Mau Revised the post to show better what I am really after and to make clear that my code snippets are not for review but to help explain the text of the post and to offer something "concrete", people can work with.